# What is the different between setting Facebook settings problematically in the run time and statically in the web config?

Tags: facebook, model-view-controller, facebook-c#-sdk

The question is when I need to set the Facebook settings in the web config and setting it dynamically in the run time, will it be different or just another way of setting the Facebook settings?

I'm using Facebook C# SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well there is no big different ,but the most important one is when you put your settings inside the web config then you are sure that you use only one Facebook application that uses you solution ,then it is ok to set it there because it is only one application

but when more than one application uses the same solution and you have to store the Facebook application setting within your database then  you need to obtain the appid in the run time within the Facebook context then load your application settings and set in in the run time ,I ask a lot of questions about that topic before look to my posts it may help you :)

and yes you can make that by creatin class that implemint IFacebookApplication and in the global.asax inthe application start do the folowing :

> FacebookApplication.SetApplication(new
>   myclassname());